# Proof $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I consider the following set:$$ \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\bar{R}}):= \{ A \cup E: A \subset \mathbb{R}, A \in \mathcal{B }(\mathbb{R}), E \subset \{-\infty, \infty\} \} $$

$\mathcal{B }(\mathbb{R})$ is the borel-sigma-algebra. Now I want to verify, that $\mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\bar{R}})$ is a sigma-algebra, too.

Obviously $\mathbb{\bar{R}}, \emptyset \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\bar{R}})$

Then: $ A \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\bar{R}}) \Rightarrow A^c \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\bar{R}}) $ 
Is this the right way? Did I miss something?

Comment: I would think you want $$ \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\bar{R}}):= \{ A \cup E:  A \in \mathcal{B }(\mathbb{R}), E \subset \{-\infty,\infty\}\} $$

Comment: No, $ \emptyset$ is not included.

Comment: I wasn't done writing. Check again.

Comment: Yes tha is the same set, isnt it?

Comment: You have stated that $ A \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\overline{R}}) \Rightarrow A^c \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{\overline{R}}) $ but you haven't explained why. Also, you need to show that $\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ is closed under countable unions.

Comment: I thought, that follows becaus of the fact, that $B(\mathbb{R^n})$ is a sigma-algebra.

Comment: But an arbitrary $A \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb R})$ isn't necessarily in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ as it may contain $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Moreover, the meaning of $A^c$ changes according to whether you consider it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: I see. I knew it was too easy. How can I argue then?

Comment: @Steven33 The complement of $A \cup E$ in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is $\overline{\mathbb R} \cap A^c \cap E^c$ $=$ $(\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}) \cap A^c \cap E^c$ $=$ $(\mathbb R \cap A^c) \cup (\{-\infty, \infty\} \cap E^c)$. Observe that $\mathbb R \cap A^c$ is a Borel set and $\{-\infty, \infty\} \cap E^c \subseteq \{-\infty, \infty\}$, so the union of these two sets (which is the complement of $A \cup E$) is in $\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$.

Comment: @Bungo So you can conlcude that $A^c \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @Steven33 An arbitrary element of $\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$ is of the form $A \cup E$ where $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $E \subset \{-\infty, \infty\}$. The argument in my previous comment shows that the complement of this arbitrary element is also in $\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$.

Comment: @Bungo: Now I see:) Thank you. How would argue that the set is closed under countable unions?

Comment: @Steven33 If $A_n \cup E_n$ is a sequence of elements in $\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$, then $\bigcup (A_n \cup E_n) = \left(\bigcup A_n\right) \cup \left(\bigcup E_n\right)$. Now observe that $\bigcup A_n \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $\bigcup E_n \subset \{-\infty, \infty\}$.